# Import readline.h library to QtCreator on Windows

Tags: c, windows, qt

I need to import readline.h library to Windows. I have already tried to import folder with libraries here:
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include
It is a library with history.h, chardefs.h, keymaps.h, readline.h, etc..

But when i try to compile program like this:

```
if ((line= readline("my_prompt$ ")) == NULL)
            exit(0);
add_history(line);
```

I recieve this message:

```
error: undefined reference to `add_history'
error: undefined reference to `impl__readline'
```

I really need it to run that library on my machine. Thanks you very much for helping!

Comment: I guess you need to link  library, e.g.: `-lreadline` in gcc arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the library path to your .pro file (**not** your Makefile - this will be rewritten everytime you change anything in your project configuration):

```
LIBS += -lreadline
```

Comment: Ok i added line: LIBS += -lreadline to my .pro file, but now there is a issue: :-1: error: cannot find -lreadline. I have to specific the path of the library somewhere? Thanks

Comment: then add QMAKE_LFLAGS += <your library's path> as well

Comment: OK I added that :  QMAKE_LFLAGS += C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\readline. It still does not work, but files with header files are in that path. The QT write this: :-1: error: cannot find C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\readline: Permission denied

Comment: `\include` is the path of the h files, not the path of the lib files

Comment: I think i did something wrong i just copy .h files to qtCreator. Can you please write me whole procedure what should I do if I want to have readline library on my Windows Qt Creator?? Thanks you very much !

Comment: you need two files: `libreadline.h` (the include file) and `libreadline.a` (the library). The former needs to be copied somewhere  where your .pro file's `INCLUDEPATH` points to, the latter where the above `QMAKE_LFLAGS` points to.